# Create Recurring Payment Profile

Tags: paypal

I am looking for the way to setup the PayPal recurring payment using API. As per the requirement, I need to charge the user $100 per month infinite. But need to give free ($0) every fourth month on three consecutive successful payment.

e.g. if the payment starts on January, it should charge $100 for Jan, Feb and March. It should not charge for April. Again it should charge $100 for May, Jun and July. while it should not charge for August. and so on.

So that user will get free subscription for every 4th month.

Please let me know how to implement this.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What have you already tried? What language are you using?